# Difference between typealias and val for object

Tags: singleton, kotlin, type-alias

For a class, it is clear that we can not use `val` to refer to a type.

For example,

```
class LongName {
    ...
}

typealias A = LongName // OK
val B = LongName // compile error
val C = LongName() // compiles, but it refers to an instance, not the class itself
```

However, for an (singleton) object, both compiles. In addition, both can be used for its members.

```
object LongName {
    val a = "123"
}

typealias A = LongName
val B = LongName

...

// In a function,
println(A.a) // compiles
println(B.a) // compiles
```

What is difference between them?

Comment: val C = LongName::class // reference to the class of LongName

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the single instance of an `object` by its name, in this case, as `LongName` (this is why you can assign it to a `val`):

```
println(LongName.a)

val longName = LongName
println(longName.a)
```

And you can also refer to its type as `LongName` (this is why you can create a `typealias` for it):

```
fun doStuff(longName: LongName) {}

typealias LN = LongName
fun doStuff(longName: LN) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a `typealias` to a class or an object will always work because you are just giving another name to it. From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html),

> Type aliases provide alternative names for existing types. If the type name is too long you can introduce a different shorter name and use the new one instead.

While assigning a `val` is different. `val` can only be used for properties or objects.

In your first example,

> val B = LongName

here the compiler tries to find an object or property and assign it to `B` which it cannot, because `LongName` is a class and it does not have any `companion object` either.

In case, if you define a companion object with the class like,

```
class LongName {
    companion object {
        val a = "123"
    }
}
```

Then you can access it like,

```
val b = LongName
info(b.a) //123
```

Though it doesn't make much sense to do it this way as you always have access to properties in `companion object` statically like, `LongName.a`.